# PHP Code to generate event to repeat in a random shuffle of intervals between 1-20 seconds

Tags: php, javascript

This program sends an email every 20 sec.

How can I amend the code to have it send an email, then pause for a random number of seconds between 1 and 20, then repeat till the end ?
Any help on this is much appreciate. Thanks in advance!

Here is the code that is associated with the Delay section of the User Interface as it is

```
if (!$delaySecs) {

$delaySecs = 20; 

}

<input name="delaySecs" type="text" value="<? print $delaySecs; ?>" size="10">
```

Answer (score 1):

As i understand you are executing the mail function in a loop for *x* number of times.Use `sleep(rand(1, 20));` before the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [sleep](http://php.net/sleep) function to pause execution.

If you are looking to pause the same amount of time between the sending of each email:

```
// $recipients is an array of email addresses    

foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
    sendEmail($recipient);
    sleep($delaySecs);
}
```

I'm assuming you already know how to get the recipients and how to send the email. The above code is an example only how to pause between the sending of emails.